# Database replication from SQL Server 2000 to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-server-2000, replication

We are SQL Server users and recently we have one database on PostgreSQL. For consistency purpose we are replication database on SQL Server 2000 to other database on SQL Server 2000 and now we would also need to replicate it to the database on PostgreSQL. We were able to do that using ODBC and Linked Server. We created an ODBC DSN for database on PostgreSQL and using that DSN we created a Linked Server on SQL Server. We were able to replicate tables from SQL Server database to that linked server and hence to PostgreSQL database successfully. Now the issue faced is while replication, the datatype bit, numeric(12,2) and decimal(12,2) are converted to character(1), character(40) and character(40) respectively. Is there any solution on how to retain those data types in PostgreSQL database ? I mean the bit should become boolean, and numeric and decimal data type should remain as it is in the replicated table of postgresql. We are using PostgreSQL 9.x

SQL Server table,

```
CREATE TABLE tmtbl 
(
    id int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Code varchar(15),
    booleancol bit,
    numericcol numeric(10, 2),
    decimalcol decimal(10, 2)
)
```

after being replicated to PostgreSQL it becomes,

```
CREATE TABLE tmtbl
(
  id integer,
  "Code" character varying(15),
  booleancol character(1),
  numericcol character(40),
  decimalcol character(40),
)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe better asked at [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: "*the datatype is converted to*": which tool does this conversion? Can you pre-create the tables manuall so that this (apparently wrong) automatic conversion does not happen?

Answer (score 1):

Please, use:

1. `boolean` type for `true`/`false` type of columns (there's no `bit` type in postgres);
2. [`NUMERIC`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) type exists also in the PostgreSQL (according to the SQL standard). But I suggest you should better use `real` PostgreSQL type, as it will be working faster.

I recommend you to create target table on the PostgreSQL side manually, specifying proper field types, as ODBC+Linked Server combination is not doing it's job properly.

You can always consult [this part](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype.html) of the official documentation for existing data types.

Comment: `real` is not a good choice if you want exact values. `numeric` is a much better choice.

Answer (score 0):

have you heard of Foreign Data Wrappers?
http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers